# Что означает int a : 1?

Tags: c++

```
struct A
{
int a : 1;
}
```

Конкретно-> int a :1;

Comment: Читайте раздел битовые поля: https://learnc.info/c/unions_and_bitfields.html
Там сказано о том, что подобной записью вы получаете доступ к отдельным битам.

Comment: А что написано по этому поводу в вашей любимой книге по С++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Битовое поле `a` размера 1. Читайте документацию

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field